# Use table function to perform actions on every row of data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, table-functions

I have a query that returns multiple records based on the Number ID (parameter) passed into it. I would like to create a table function which takes in "num_id" (number datatype) as a parameter, passes that into a query, performs operations on every record of that query's result, and returns "mainKey" (character datatype) as a record.

Every tutorial I find has me create an Object and Table of that Object before I create the function.. I don't quite understand the use of this.

I also don't understand where I would add my original query (the one that retrieves records from a DB).

Can anyone please show me how I would achieve this? I was able to perform actions on every record

Here is my work so far:

```
-- create object
CREATE TYPE test_t AS OBJECT
    (mainKey char);

-- create collection type:
CREATE TYPE testSet_t AS TABLE OF test_t;

--Create table function: "test_tf"
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_tf 
    (num_id IN NUMBER)
    RETURN char
    IS
        z char;
    BEGIN
        SELECT one_column_name from testSet_t
    END;
```

I used to be able to perform operations in every record with a cursor and a for loop... but here I was only able to print data as dbms_output. I need to be able to produce some records as a result. Here is that cursor attempt:

```
DECLARE
    cursor cur_test IS
    <my select statement which returns 4 records>;
BEGIN
    FOR ln_index IN cur_test
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(ln_index.one_column_name);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(ln_index.another_column_name);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

The above code works fine and prints to dbms output... but I need to be able to perform operations to the data in each line, and return records instead of DBMS Output.

Comment: Please, clarify what do you mean by "rows of records" and "returns record". Is it a real PL/SQL record type (which cannot be stored in SQL table as it's a PL/SQL type, SQL has only Object type of similar structure) or  some specific terminology of your data model?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Instead of "rows of records" I mean just records (that which is returned from a simple select statement). Same for "returns record" - I need the output to be records.

Comment: Ahh, I see. You want a function to apply to some result set and transform/derive particular column of every row, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct

Comment: I've updated the answer with another approach using PTF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Oracle 19c (19.7) and above you may use [`SQL_MACRO`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/newft/sql-macros-sqm.html) to create a table-valued function that may be used as parameterized view.

```
create table t(id, val)
as
select level, mod(level, 4)
from dual
connect by level < 10
```

```
create function f_do_smth(
  p1 int, p2 in int
) return timestamp
is
begin
  /*To demonstrate some work*/
  dbms_session.sleep(trunc(p1+p2)/10);
  return systimestamp;
end;/
```

```
create function f_get_t_byval (
  p_val in int
) return varchar2
sql_macro(table)
is
begin
  return '
    select
      t.*,
      f_do_smth(
        p1 => t.id,
        /*Here we use a parameter as a parameter
          for processing, not only as a filter*/
        p2 => f_get_t_byval.p_val
      ) as processed_result
    from t
    where val >= f_get_t_byval.p_val
  ';
end;/
```

```
select *
from f_get_t_byval(p_val => 2)
```

| ID | VAL | PROCESSED_RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 16-NOV-22 22.18.31.164939000 |
| 3 | 3 | 16-NOV-22 22.18.31.668203000 |
| 6 | 2 | 16-NOV-22 22.18.32.508269000 |
| 7 | 3 | 16-NOV-22 22.18.33.468175000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sLY4VXF1)

**UPD**.
If you want to have a more generic way to apply something to arbitrary table, you may also use [Polymorphic Table Function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/DBMS_TF.html) (PTF) concept, implementing transformation logic inside PTF package and applying it to the different tables (or CTEs). It is available since 18c.

Below is an example of application of the same `f_do_smth` to the table and column specified in the function call (runtime), not in the implementation. Please note, that `tab` and `cols` parameters (of type `table` and `columns` respectively) are **identifiers**, so they cannot be parameterized (via bind variables or string expressions) in this example.

> ```
> create or replace package pkg_proc as
>   /*Package to implement PTF*/
>
>   function describe(
>     tab in out dbms_tf.table_t,
>     cols in out dbms_tf.columns_t,
>     p_val in int,
>     proc_res_nm in dbms_id default 'RES'
>   ) return dbms_tf.describe_t
>   ;
>
>   procedure fetch_rows(
>     p_val in int,
>     proc_res_nm in dbms_id default 'RES'
>   );
> end pkg_proc;
> ```

> ```
> create or replace package body pkg_proc as
>
>   function describe(
>     /*Input table identifier*/
>     tab in out dbms_tf.table_t,
>     /*Input columns' identifiers to be processed by the function logic*/
>     cols in out dbms_tf.columns_t,
>     /*Parameter to be passed to the processing function*/
>     p_val in int,
>     /*New column name with the result of processing*/
>     proc_res_nm in dbms_id default 'RES'
>   ) return dbms_tf.describe_t
>   as
>     l_col_tmp dbms_tf.column_t;
>   begin
>     /*Mark input column to be used for subsequent row processing*/
>     for i in 1..tab.column.count loop
>       for j in 1..cols.count() loop
>         if tab.column(i).description.name = cols(j) then
>           /*Pass it to the FETCH step making it
>             available in the implementation logic*/
>           tab.column(i).for_read := TRUE;
>           /*Do not modify this column during processing*/
>           tab.column(i).pass_through := TRUE;
>         end if;
>       end loop;
>     end loop;
>
>     /*Declare new output column*/
>     return dbms_tf.describe_t(
>       new_columns => dbms_tf.columns_new_t(
>         1 => dbms_tf.column_metadata_t(
>           name => proc_res_nm,
>           type => dbms_tf.type_timestamp
>         )
>       )
>     );
>   end;
>
>   procedure fetch_rows(
>     p_val in int,
>     proc_res_nm in dbms_id default 'RES'
>   )
>   /*Process rowset and perform "action" on each row*/
>   as
>     rowset dbms_tf.row_set_t;
>     num_rows pls_integer;
>     col dbms_tf.tab_number_t;
>     new_col dbms_tf.tab_timestamp_t;
>   begin
>     /*Get "rows" projectiong only required column.
>     May be replaced by get_row_set to obtain all for_read=TRUE columns
>     */
>     dbms_tf.get_col(
>       columnId => 1,
>       collection => col
>     );
>
>     for rn in 1..col.count() loop
>       /*Calculate new column value in the same row*/
>       new_col(rn) := f_do_smth(
>         p1 => col(rn),
>         p2 => p_val
>       );
>     end loop;
>
>     /*Put calculated column to output*/
>     dbms_tf.put_col(
>       /*The same ID as in DESCRIBE procedure*/
>       columnid => 1,
>       collection => new_col
>     );
>   end;
> end pkg_proc;
> ```

> ```
> create or replace function f_apply_do_smt(
>   tab in table,
>   col in columns,
>   p_val in int,
>   proc_res_nm in dbms_id default 'RES'
> )
> /*Function to apply f_do_smth using PTF*/
> return table pipelined
> row polymorphic using pkg_proc;
> ```

And application of this function to different columns of the table.

- column `val`

```
select *
from f_apply_do_smt(t, columns(val), 2)
where val > 1
```

| ID | VAL | RES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-11-17 12:49:55.532608000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-11-17 12:49:57.212626000 |
| 6 | 2 | 2022-11-17 12:49:58.571941000 |
| 7 | 3 | 2022-11-17 12:50:00.252031000 |

- column `id`

```
select *
from f_apply_do_smt(t, columns(id), 2)
```

| ID | VAL | RES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-11-17 12:56:33.932650000 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-11-17 12:56:35.292699000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2022-11-17 12:56:36.972652000 |
| 4 | 0 | 2022-11-17 12:56:39.052664000 |
| 5 | 1 | 2022-11-17 12:56:41.452734000 |
| 6 | 2 | 2022-11-17 12:56:44.172713000 |
| 7 | 3 | 2022-11-17 12:56:47.212648000 |
| 8 | 0 | 2022-11-17 12:56:50.572676000 |
| 9 | 1 | 2022-11-17 12:56:54.252680000 |

- and another table (CTE) with another column

```
with sample_tab(a) as (
  select level
  from dual
  connect by level < 4
)
select *
from f_apply_do_smt(sample_tab, columns(a), 1, 'AND_EVEN_CTE')
```

| A | AND_EVEN_CTE |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-11-17 12:58:59.852804000 |
| 2 | 2022-11-17 12:59:00.892778000 |
| 3 | 2022-11-17 12:59:02.252728000 |